# Array of Doubly Linked Lists

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I would like to create an array where each element is a doubly linked list. Here's what I have so far:

```
public ArrayOfLists() {
    this.limit = limit;  //limit of Nodes in each element of listArray
    listArray = (DoublyLinkedList<E>[]) new DoublyLinkedList[3];
    listArray[0] = new DoublyLinkedList<E>(); 
    listArray[1] = new DoublyLinkedList<E>();
    listArray[2] = new DoublyLinkedList<E>();
    size = 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is conceptually correct, but I kind of see this as a 2D array. I'm confused with how I go about adding and removing objects from the lists stored in this array. For example,

```
public void add(E obj) {
    //some stuff
 }

 public void remove(int index) {
    //some stuff
 }
```

Could I somehow access the already implemented methods in my doublyLinkedList class to assist with this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Why don't you use a `DoublyLinkedList<DoublyLinkedList<E>> listOfLists`? You can access them by `listOfLists.add(DoublyLinkedList<E> e);`, `listOfList.get(idx).add(E e);`, `listOfLists.get(idx); //returning a DublyLinkedList<E>`, `listOfLists.get(idx1).get(idx2); // returning an element`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what logic you will use to figure out which slot of the array you want to add your `obj` to, but this is how you would do it (after implementing `calculateArraySlotSomehow` of course):

```
public void add(E obj)
{
    int index = calculateArraySlotSomehow(obj);

    listArray[index].add(obj);
}
```

Based on your comments, you could implement `calculateArraySlotSomehow` something like this:

```
private int calculateArraySlotSomehow(E obj)
{
    // 'count' is the total number of elements that are already
    //         stored in this data structure
    // 'size' is the number of array elements
    // 'limit' is the number of elements per list

    int slot = count / limit;

    if (slot >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + slot + ", Size: " + size);
    }

    return slot;
}
```

And then you would have to change your `add` implementation to:

```
public void add(E obj)
{
    int index = calculateArraySlotSomehow(obj);

    listArray[index].add(obj);

    count++;
}
```

Note that this is not thread-safe.

I'm curious as to what you are actually trying to accomplish, because I have a feeling that you might be going out of your way to complicate things.